# How to display image inside column with DT in R Markdown or shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, dt

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
df <- data.frame(image = "http://www.ufotm.com/data/attachment/forum/201203/11/110705gf50r55yqcka5ffz.jpg", title = "here is a title")
DT::renderDataTable(df,
                escape = FALSE,
                rownames = FALSE,
                extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
                    dom = 'lBfrtip',
                    buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print')
                    )
)
```
````

I have the image url. I try to insert image in a rmarkdown or shiny app. I prefer `DT` library because I can download excel file then. How can I do that?

PS: I want to provide excel or pdf file for my user to download as well.

I try to use [DataTables Options](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html), and find a [related question](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32924/is-it-possible-to-show-image-in-datatable#Comment_88437). I tried the below code and it shows error.

```
---
    title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

df <- data.frame(image = "http://www.ufotm.com/data/attachment/forum/201203/11/110705gf50r55yqcka5ffz.jpg", title = "here is a title")
DT::renderDataTable(df,
                    escape = FALSE,
                    rownames = FALSE,
                    extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
                        dom = 'lBfrtip',
                        buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'),
                        columnDefs = list(list(targets = 1,
                                               data = "img",
                                               render = JS(
                                                   'function ( url, type, full) {',
                                                   'return '<img height="75%" width="75%" src="'+full[7]+'"/>';',
                                                   '}'
                                               )
                        ))
                    )
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use html tags and use `escape = FALSE` as below:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
df <- data.frame(image = c('<img src="http://www.ufotm.com/data/attachment/forum/201203/11/110705gf50r55yqcka5ffz.jpg" height="52"></img>' ), title = "here is a title")
DT::renderDataTable(df, escape = FALSE)
```
````

You will get something like this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution works. Is it possible provide excel or pdf file of the displayed result?

Comment: I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Could you accept the answer if it answered your question?

Comment: Yes. It helps me a lot.